# Interaction.Behaviors does not work in SplitView?

Tags: winrt-xaml, windows-10-universal, template10

I use `SplitView` for my XAML page. Inside the `SplitView`, trigger behavior doesn't work.

For example:

```
<SplitView.Content>
 <Grid>
  <Button x:Name="Button">
    <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
      <Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Click" >
         <Core:GoToStateAction StateName="SplitViewState />
      </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
    </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
  </Button>

 </Grid>
</SplitView.Content>
```

When clicking the button, nothing happens. It works on elements outside the `SplitView`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you missed setup `TargetObject` value.

```
<Button Content="click me"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <I:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Click" >
            <Core:GoToStateAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=MySplitView}"
                                  StateName="OpenOverlayLeft"/>
        </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
    </I:Interaction.Behaviors>
</Button>
```

**UPDATED**

Look at behavior with 4 buttons which placed inside `SplitView.Content`, `SplitView.Pane` and outside. All works very well.

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <SplitView x:Name="MySplitView"
               PaneBackground="Gray"
               DisplayMode="CompactOverlay"
               IsPaneOpen="True"
               CompactPaneLength="50"
               OpenPaneLength="280">
        <SplitView.Pane>
            <Grid>
                <Button Content="close inside"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Click" >
                            <core:GoToStateAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=MySplitView}"
                                                  StateName="Closed"/>
                        </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                </Button>
            </Grid>
        </SplitView.Pane>

        <SplitView.Content>
            <Grid>
                <Button Content="open inside"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Click">
                            <core:GoToStateAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=MySplitView}"
                                                  StateName="OpenOverlayLeft"/>
                        </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                </Button>
            </Grid>
        </SplitView.Content>

    </SplitView>

    <Grid Grid.Column="1"
          Background="Aquamarine">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button Content="open outside"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Click">
                    <core:GoToStateAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=MySplitView}"
                                          StateName="OpenOverlayLeft"/>
                </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        </Button>

        <Button Content="close outside"
                Grid.Column="1"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Click" >
                    <core:GoToStateAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=MySplitView}"
                                          StateName="Closed"/>
                </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Look how it works:

[image]

Comment: Is your button inside SplitView (content or pane doesn't matter) or just Grid? because same command works if button is inside simple grid but doesn't work if button is inside splitview (or grid that is inside splitView). I have SplitViewState Visual state inside VisualStateGroup and i want to go to that state. Target object is VisualStateGroup?

Comment: solved by removing SplitView and using Hamburger from Template10